# SwiftUI Picker in ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui

Wondering if this is possible or if there is another approach I should use. I want to display X number of pickers on a view, where X is a value input by the user. Each of the pickers will have the same options, but should be able to select different values. The values that are selected need to be saved in order.

My attempt:

```
struct User: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}

class LineupViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var selectedSize = 8
   @Published var usersInOrder: [User]
   @Published var fullList: [User]
   ...
}


struct Lineup: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: LineupViewModel
    ...
    ForEach(0..<viewModel.selectedSize, id: \.self) { i in
         HStack {
             Text(String(i+1)+": ")
             Picker("User", selection: $viewModel.usersInOrder[i]) {
                ForEach(viewModel.$fullList) { r in
                    Text(String(r.firstName+" "+r.lastName))
                }
             }.pickerStyle(.menu)
         }
     }
}
```

usersInOrder may be an empty array if making a new lineup, or could be an array of Users the same size as selectedSize. fullList will always be the list of all Users. Currently this is giving me an error on the view saying *The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time*. Is there a way to update usersInOrder in the correct index of the array depending on value of the Picker?

Comment: probably a typo, have you tried `ForEach(viewModel.fullList){...}`, note no `$`. Note you should not use `ForEach(0..<viewModel.selectedSize, id: \.self)`, this is bad practice. Restructure your code, as it is it will crash with index out of range.

Comment: I assume each User object should be selected only once?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just a few touches:

1. Make picker a separate view for convenience, and make it bind its selection to a parent view:

```
struct UserPicker: View {
    
    @Binding var selection: User // <-- Binding to publish the selected value to a parent
    
    var options: [User]
    
    var labelText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
             Text(labelText)
             Picker("User", selection: $selection) {
                 ForEach(options, id: \.self) { r in // <-- notice the use of id
                    Text(String(r.firstName+" "+r.lastName))
                }
             }.pickerStyle(.menu)
         }
    }
}
```

2. Your main view shows each of those, with binding on `viewModel.usersInOrder[i]`

```
struct Lineup: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: LineupViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<viewModel.selectedSize, id: \.self) { i in
            UserPicker(
                selection: $viewModel.usersInOrder[i], // <-- Binding
                options: viewModel.fullList, // <-- no need to bind, just values
                labelText: String(i+1)+": ")
        }
}
```

Comment: `ForEach` is a `View` not a for loop, it'll crash on `usersInOrder[i]`

Comment: @malhal No, this won't crash (and I wouldn't post a solution if I didn't run it first). There are drawbacks in this approach - for sure. It's better to iterate over items, not indexes - for sure. But this is how OP coded it, and I had no reason to change to answer the question.